# Querying an Embedded element & Foreign Key Element within Android Room

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-room

I'm new to how the Room Database works particularly Querying and was wondering how one would go about querying the following.

1. Querying an object that contains an embedded object within it, based
   on the embedded object.
2. Querying an object that contains a foreign key

@Entity

```
@Entity
public class Car {
    @PrimaryKey()
    private String id;
    @Embedded()
    private Engine engine
    @Ignore
    private List<Tire> tires
    ... //relevant getters and setters

}

public class Engine {
    private String id;
    private String type;
    private String name;
}


@Entity(foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(
  entity = Car.class, parentColumn = "id", childColumn ="carIdFk")
}
public class Tire { 
   @PrimaryKey(autogenerated=true)
   private int id;
   private String model;
   private String rimModel;
   private String cardIdFk;
}

@Dao
public interface CarDao {
//Need a query to retrieve all cars where engine id == <somevalue>
//Need a query to retrieve all cars where tire model == <somevalue>
}

@Dao
public interface TyreDao {
//Need a query to retrieve all cars where tire id == <somevalue>
}
```